# Various questions about arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

So I am trying to learn C right now, and I am writing basic scripts to ensure I have the foundations, but I am struggeling to understand the problem with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Linking external libraries.
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    /* First I will set my variables.
    */
    double std; //Standard Deviation
    double sqdif;
    double avg;
    int N=10; //number of elements
    double X[10]; //Not sure why I cannot use N here.
    int i;


    /* Now I will prompt for input and listen for values,
    then assign those values respectively.*/

    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("Please enter X[ %d ", i);
        printf("]: ");
        scanf("%d", &X[i-1]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        avg = avg + X[i];
        printf("\n %d", X[i]);
    }
    avg = avg / N;
    printf("\nThe average is: %d", avg);


    return 0;
}
```

My two main questions are as such:

1. Why can I not use N to define my array X?
2. Why is my script returning:

> 1
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>        4196197
>       The average is: 4196197

for my results? If you see the error in the code please let me know!

Thanks,

Ps. this is obviously an incomplete script.

Comment: For question 1: What error do you get? If you try double X[N]; ?

Comment: You can't use `N` as your subscript in `double X[N]` because `N` is variable. Try `const int N = 10;` instead, and you need to be using the C99 standard. Change `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` to `for (avg = 0, i = 0; i < N; i++)` to initialize `avg` before the loop.

Comment: Calling `scanf("%d", &X[i-1])` with `double X[10]` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Your printf's are also using %d for a double.  Use %f.

Comment: be consistent. loops starts either from `0` or `1`. Goes to `N` or `11`., `i-1` vs `i`. It's a huge mess.

Comment: You cannot use a VLA (`double X[N];`), because you are for some reason using pre-1999 C, which does not have them, and your compiler (or its mode) does not allow them as an extension. Anyway, an array of length `N` has indices `0 .. N-1`, never `N`.

Comment: Karoly, it works. I have it set that way for a reason, which is beacuse I want to prompt for x[1] to the user rather than X[0], just for visual reasons. That part was sound. Thanks though.

Comment: Kiss, thanks for that info. I need to look more into how the %'s work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I not use N to define my array X?

Prior to the 1999 standard, array sizes had to be specified using a *constant expression* whose value could be computed at compile time; this means either a numeric literal such as `10`, a *preprocessor macro* that would expand to a numeric literal such as `#define N 10`, or an arithmetic expression involving literals or macros that expand to literals:

```
#define X 10
...
int arr1[X];     
int arr2[2 * X];
int arr3[10];
int arr4[2 * 4 + 2];
```

All of `X`, `2 * X`, `10`, and `2 * 4 + 2` are constant expressions, and can be evaluated at compile time.

In your code, `N` is not a constant expression; it's simply a regular variable whose value is not established until run time.

C99 introduced the concept of a *variable-length array* whose size could be determined at run time. If you had used a C99 compiler (gcc with the `-std=c99` option, for example), then your code would have compiled.   Visual Studio's support of C99 is minimal at best, and I don't think the current version supports VLAs at all.

VLAs have a number of limitations; you cannot use an initializer with them, nor can you declare them at file scope (outside of any function).  You want to be careful with them, since memory for them is allocated from the stack like any other local (`auto`) variable.

The 2011 C standard made VLA's optional (my understanding is that they were a major pain to implement properly), so they may not be that well supported going forward.

> Why is my script returning:
>   1 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 The average is: 4196197

As others have pointed out, you're using the wrong conversion specifiers in your `printf` and `scanf` calls.  `%d` expects the corresponding  argument to have type `int` (for `printf`) and `int *` (for `scanf`).  You'll want to use `%f` and `%lf` instead:

```
scanf("%lf", &X[i-1]);  // %lf expects pointer to double
...
printf("%f", X[i-1]);  // %f expects double
```

Note that conversion specifiers in `printf` and `scanf` are not symmetrical, and this is one case where it matters.  To read a `double`, you *must* use `%lf`; a regular `%f` expects the corresponding argument to be a pointer to `float`.  However, you can use `%f` to print either a double or a float.

Check your handy C reference manual for both functions.

You also need to initialize `avg`:

```
double avg = 0.0;
```

Comment: Very thurough! Excellent responce. This answered my questions to the key.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("\n %d", X[i]);
```

should be

```
printf("\n %f", X[i]);
```

since `X[i]` is of type `double`.

Even though it isn't wrong please consider rewriting the for loop for  better readability like this, and of course change `%d` to `%f` again:

```
 for (i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Please enter X[ %d ]:", i);
        scanf("%f", &X[i]);
    }
```

Comment: The same fix needs to be applied to the `scanf` statement too.

Comment: Thanks! The printf statement was particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not use N to define my array X?

You can. You are using variable length array. Variable length arrays are introduced in C99. You need to compile your code in C99 mode (use `-std=c99` option).

> Why is my script returning:
>   1 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 4196197 The average is: 4196197

`avg` is not initialized. Initialize it with `0` before using in statement:

```
avg = avg + X[i];
```

otherwise program will behave erroneous because of undefined behavior. Also note that `%lf` and `%f` is needed to scan and print, respectively, the `double` data type .

```
double avg = 0; /* Initialize it with 0 */
int N=10; 
double X[N]; /* Variable length array. C99 mode needed to compile the code */
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Coming from Java things are a bit different, so just learning as I go. Appreciate it.

Comment: Note that VLAs are now *optional* in C2011, so support for them may be spotty going forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
avg = avg + X[i];
```

`avg` is never initialized and the value of `avg` is undeterminate so you see undefined behavior.

You have another UB

```
printf("\n %d", X[i]);
```

Using wrong format specifier in `printf()` will be UB.

```
printf("\n %lf", X[i]);
```

You scan values from `0-9` and print values from `0-10` , here again you are using uninitialized `a[10]` element.

Put together change should be like:

```
 avg = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Please enter X[ %d ", i);
        printf("]: ");
        scanf("%lf", &X[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        avg = avg + X[i];
        printf("\n %lf", X[i]);
    }
    avg = avg / N;
    printf("\nThe average is: %lf", avg);
```

VLA(Variable length array's) are supported from C99 and you can use them

```
int N = 10;
double X[N]; /* Valid */
```

Comment: whatever. It was bad wording.